# CollectionDifference on Subset of Fields

Tags: swift

Consider the following code snippet which creates a diff of 2 collections of `Foo` structs

```swift
struct Foo {

    let v: String
    let other: Int
}

extension Foo: Hashable {

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(v)
    }
}

extension Foo: CustomStringConvertible {

    var description: String {
        return v
    }
}

var col1 = [
    Foo(v: "a", other: 1),
    Foo(v: "b", other: 1),
    Foo(v: "c", other: 1),
]

var col2 = [
    Foo(v: "a", other: 1),
    Foo(v: "c", other: 1),
    Foo(v: "d", other: 1),
]

let diff = col2.difference(from: col1)

diff.forEach { change in
    switch change {
    case let .remove(offset, _, _):
        print("remove: \(offset)")
    case let .insert(offset, _, _):
        print("insert: \(offset)")
    }
}
```

This will produce the following `print` output as expected:

```
remove: 1
insert: 2
```

Now change the `other` field of `col2` to 2 like this

```swift
var col2 = [
    Foo(v: "a", other: 2),
    Foo(v: "c", other: 2),
    Foo(v: "d", other: 2),
]
```

Since I am producing a hash value only from `v`, I would expect the same output, but what I actually get is this.

```swift
remove: 2
remove: 1
remove: 0
insert: 0
insert: 1
insert: 2
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Seems I manually need to implement `Equatable`, but why?

Comment: If you only had declared a conformance to `Hashable`, the compiler would have syntheiszed an implementation of `hash(into:)` which is based off all the fields of `Foo` (`v` and `other`). The conformance to `Hashable` also implies a conformance to `Equatable`, which the compiler also synthesized for you (by making a `==` also based off `v` and `other`). By providing your own `hash(into:)` (based off only `v`), and not your own `==` (which is still based off `v` and `other`), you've broken the contract of `Hashable`. Honestly, the compiler should emit warnings (errors?) in such cases.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica: No, the only requirement is that equal values have the same hash. It is *allowed* (and sometimes unavoidable, as for strings), that distinct values have the same hash. – The contract would only be broken if you implement a custom == (based only on `v`) but use the synthesized hash (based on all stored properties). *That* is a case which should emit a warning/error.

Comment: @MartinR Ah crap, I knew that, I got it mixed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`BidirectionalCollection.difference(from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/bidirectionalcollection/3200721-difference) computes the “difference” of two collections, based on the *equality* of their elements. Since you did not implement `==` for `Foo`, the compiler synthesizes a default implementation, and that compares all (stored) properties.

Adopting the `Hashable` protocol can improve the performance, but does not affect the equality of values: distinct elements *can* have the same hash value.

If you provide our own implementation of `Equatable` as

```
extension Foo: Equatable {
    static func ==(lhs: Foo, rhs: Foo) -> Bool {
        return lhs.v == rhs.v
    }
}
```

then

```
Foo(v: "a", other: 1) == Foo(v: "a", other: 2) // etc.
```

and the output is the expected

```
remove: 1
insert: 2
```

*Alternatively,* use [``BidirectionalCollection.difference(from:by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3200716-difference) and pass a custom equivalence test:

```
let diff = col2.difference(from: col1, by: { $0.v == $1.v })
```

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't make sense to me that this should be like this. `Hashable` is a stronger guarantee than `Equatable`, therefore every `Equatable` that was synthesized by the compiler from `Hashable` should have equality based on the hash value. Also it doesn't make sense at all that an object with the same `hashValue` should not be equal.

Comment: @ErikAigner: The only “contract” is that equal elements must have the same hash value, but not the other way around. – Take *strings* as an example: There are at most 2^64 possible hash values, but infinitely many different strings. That makes it *impossible* that all distinct strings have distinct hash values.

Comment: But on that basis, the requirement for a `DiffableCollection` should not be `Hashable` but only `Equatable`.

Comment: @ErikAigner: The requirement *is* that Element conforms to Equatable.

Comment: My fault, `Hashable` comes from my code and was the inferred type.